# Bootstrap dropdown not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I try to make a dropdown for some odd reason when its clicked the dropdown menu displays off the page and I cant even see it in my actual website but JSFIDDLE shows it off the screen. Here is the JSFIDDLE where I was testing.

[Click here for JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s78co384/)

Here is what I am currently doing.

```
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#">Applications<b class="caret"></b></button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="/app/">My Applications</a></li>
     <li><a href="/app/staff">Staff Dashboard</a></li>
     <li><a href="/app/apply">Apply</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent element with the position property not set to static, i.e. to either relative, absolute, or fixed. The dropdown is using an absolute position with `top:100%`, so if there is no parent item with a position set, then it will use the window element as its reference, hence why it opens at the bottom of the page. Just set the immediate parent of the `<ul>` to have the position set.

Check out the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s78co384/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code.Like missing div, tabindex etc.I fixed it up and check whether it helps you-

```
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
 type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Applications
 <span class="caret"></span></button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
 My Apllications</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
 Staff Board</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Apply
 </a>  
 </li>


 </ul>
 </div>
```

Working fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/vashuStrPro/6p0ux8st/

Comment: For somereason it doesnt work on my website maybe you can mess around with it through inspect element? The navbar has 3 dropdowns but they work on my forum header but not my actual website pages


Broken: http://axiom-network.com/donate


Works: http://axiom-network.com/forum

Comment: When i turn the display:none off on the dropdown menu it displays fine but it just wont display when i click the button